# explicit type declaration in dart and use of 'as' keyword

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart

In typescript

```
//user is coming from firebase Users collection    
let userData = user.data() as {name:string, age:int}
```

What will be the alternatives of above code in dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Json` like data type in dart is `Map` but it's handy to code.
The most efficient way is using `Json Serialization`.

Use a `User` model, and parse `json` to it,

```
User userData = User.fromJson(user.data());
```

You can generate `Model class directly from Json` automatically from [here](https://app.quicktype.io/).
So no pain in the neck.

`User model` class will be like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
    User({
        this.name,
        this.age,
    });

    String name;
    int age;

    User copyWith({
        String name,
        int age,
    }) => 
        User(
            name: name ?? this.name,
            age: age ?? this.age,
        );

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        name: json["name"],
        age: json["age"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
    };
}
```

Happy coding TT

Comment: Feel free to give it as accepted answer so that others with same issue can easily know the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can handle the data if it is coming from FireBase.

```
class MessageStreams extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return Center(
               child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                 backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
               ),
           );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message['text'];
          final messageSender = message['sender'];
          print(loggedInUser);
          print(loggedInUser.email);
          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
          if (currentUser == messageSender) {}
          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
             messageSender, messageText, currentUser == messageSender);

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
      }
      return Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          reverse: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
          children: messageBubbles,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

}

Comment: I want to get the document using a function so that I can use it in a bloc or cubit. I would prefer not to perform network request and ui designing in a same file. Anyway thanks for your contribution.